# Top comments on Stack Exchange profile?

Tags: feature-request, comments, network-profile

When I view my Stack Exchange profile, it lists my highest voted questions and answers for the entire network. Can we see our top comments as well?

Comment: Once, [Jeff wrote](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/comments-now-with-flags-and-votes/): *"your best comments will also show up in your user profile page, but this isn’t implemented yet."* (That said, I don't really think upvoted comments mean a lot. When they are important, they should be merged with a question or answer instead, I'd say.)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98125/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-highest-voted-comment-on-a-particular-se-site

Answer (score 4):

Not exact one, but there is a API query for each site like this for example

> http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/46011/comments?page=1&pagesize=100&sort=Votes

Comment: Probably a greasemonkey script can combine those all and new tab.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah... not so much:

- Dude, I know you don't have that many friends.  I was actually being nice when I put down 100, but if it makes you feel better let's put down 1,000, ok?
- *"Why can’t there be an “ultimate” programming language?"* - **Because Chuck Norris is busy**
- You win 1 internet.  Prize may be redeemed at the ARPANET counter.
- Q: *what do you consider to be your forte?*  A: Well, I like to keep it between my three-tay nine, and four-tay one
- Rule 37: There is no overkill.  There is only "open fire", and "time to reload".
- Scaled pixels have had that fish-skin texture removed from them, usually through mechanical abrasion.
- I have found a truly marvelous fault in your solution which this box is too small to contain.