# How can I find users with a specific number of earned/offered bounties?

Tags: support, bounties, data-explorer

How can I find users with a specific number of earned or/and offered bounties?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331567/how-can-i-look-up-any-bounties-active-and-previous-ones-i-ever-offered-with-an/331568#331568

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the Stack Exchange Data Explorer can do it for you, if you're comfortable with the results being up-to-date until the last Sunday morning (UTC).

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1713002/users-by-offered-bounties?Minimum=45&Maximum=55) is a query for offered bounties, which succeeds in listing [you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/339911/%ce%b1%ce%bb%ce%b5%cf%87%ce%bf%ce%bb%cf%85%cf%84?tab=bounties&sort=offered); [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1713004/users-by-earned-bounties?Minimum=100&Maximum=110) one for earned bounties, which lists [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9?tab=bounties&sort=earned). In the latter case, the result is off by one - could be a deleted post, which is not listed in SEDE, or due to [caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Comment: Ha - you are right! :-) I wonder if there could be a filter for bounties put on *other user's questions*?

Comment: @uhoh I've added that information to [the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1713015/most-generous-users-across-the-network-in-terms-of-bounties) now.

Comment: Thanks - omg I'm way way down in bounty rep on other people's questions. It would be fun (but certianly not necessary) if one could push a button and resort by each of the three reputation columns, with total being the default. One could also add a "tything ratio" which is bounty on others' questions divided by total. For example mine is less than 27% while Jorge Castro's is 96%!

Comment: Unfortunately, [sort is disabled on queries with such a large output](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329950/295232). You're free to download the CSV and do some sorting / calculations in your favorite spreadsheet app :)

Comment: Yep, got it, makes sense. *Thanks!*