# How can I see the percentages of the data coming from different websites on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I have to write a data description of the data collected using the query below.

```
SELECT p.Title,p.Body,c.Text

FROM Posts p
JOIN Comments c ON c.PostId = p.Id
--  filter on tags
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id) -- find question
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
--
WHERE p.Body like '%Winter Bash%'
AND p.CreationDate < '2015-12-31'
And p.CreationDate > '2011-01-01'
AND t.tagname like 'winter-bash%'
ORDER BY p.CreationDate ASC
```

And it would be nice if I can find how many percentages of these data coming from the different websites of Stack Exchange. For example, Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Exchange, etc.

Is there a way I can achieve that?

Comment: That data is per-site. Run the query for the other sites by using the site switcher.

Comment: In this way, I need to manually switch hundreds of sites and that would be so time-consuming. Is there any easier way?

Comment: There are several cross-site query templates out there. [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1287917/hot-meta-posts-networkwide) is one based off the one I currently use; [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/926495/tags-networkwide-comparison) is a slightly older example. The answers [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83570/295232) provide templates with database cursors which I usually try to avoid, but that's just my personal choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following [multi-database query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1354803)

I've only moved the `Body like '%Winter Bash%'`  clause to the final result as that where clause is a nightmare once that gets selected in the final query plan. Notice I limited the sites to query to just Meta sites as that seemed logical given your tag selection.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

create table #result (site sysname
                    , hostname sysname
                    , Title nvarchar(250)
                    , postid int
                    , Body nvarchar(max)
                    , Text nvarchar(600)
                    , creationdate datetime)

select @sql = N'insert into #result' + STRING_AGG(concat(N'
select ''', name ,N''' as site
     , ''',hostname ,N'''
     , p.Title
     , p.id
     , p.Body
     , c.Text
     , p.creationdate
     
FROM ', quotename(name), N'.dbo.Posts p
JOIN ', quotename(name), N'.dbo.Comments c ON c.PostId = p.Id
--  filter on tags
inner join ', quotename(name), N'.dbo.posttags pt on pt.postid = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id) -- find question
inner join ', quotename(name), N'.dbo.tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
--
WHERE -- p.Body like ''%Winter Bash%''
-- AND 
p.CreationDate < ''2015-12-31''
And p.CreationDate > ''2011-01-01''
AND t.tagname like ''winter-bash%''
'),N' 
union all')
from (select convert(nvarchar(max),name) name
    -- , convert(nvarchar(max),sitename)  sitename
    -- , meta
    -- , domain
     ,  concat( 
        -- based on an idea from Glorfindel 
        -- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321181
        (case sitename
        WHEN 'Audio' THEN 'video'
        WHEN 'Beer' THEN 'alcohol'
        WHEN 'CogSci' THEN 'psychology'
        WHEN 'Garage' THEN 'mechanics'
        WHEN 'Health' THEN 'medicalsciences'
        WHEN 'Moderators' THEN 'communitybuilding'
        WHEN 'Photography' THEN 'photo'
        WHEN 'Programmers' THEN 'softwareengineering'
        WHEN 'Vegetarian' THEN 'vegetarianism'
        WHEN 'Writers' THEN 'writing'
        WHEN 'Br' THEN 'pt'
        WHEN 'Mathoverflow' THEN concat((meta+'.'), sitename)
        ELSE case when sitename = domain then null else sitename end
        end +'.')
        , (case 
           when sitename <> 'mathoverflow' then (meta+'.') 
           else null 
           end) 
        , (case 
           when sitename <> 'mathoverflow' then concat((domain + '.'), 'com') 
           else 'net' 
           end)
        ) hostname
from (
select name
, case parsename(name,1) 
  when 'Meta' then parsename(name,2)
  else parsename(name,1) 
  end [sitename]
, case parsename(name,1) 
  when 'Meta' then 'meta'
  else null
  end [meta]
  , coalesce(parsename(name,3), parsename(name,2)) [domain]
from sys.databases
where database_id > 5
and (name like '%.Meta' or name = 'StackExchange.Meta')
) dbs
) dbsall

exec (@sql)



select *
from #result
where Body like '%Winter Bash%'
```

when run today this is what the resultset will look like:

[image: result multi site]

SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday.
Give a big shout-out to [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) for the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) she wrote.
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).