# Most upvoted comments across Stack Exchange (Cross site query)

Tags: discussion, support, comments, data-explorer, up-votes

I was interested in finding out the most upvoted comments per user across the entire Stack Exchange network (cross-site query).

I found [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60098/my-most-upvoted-comments-including-comment-text), which works very well, but only for one site at a time, so it very hard to obtain the results for the entire network.

Is it possible to somehow fork the query to perform a search across all Stack Exchange sites that the user has an account on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used my old [multi-db template](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1004129/multi-db-template-with-hostname) and transferred your query in it.  Here is the [resulting query.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1384827?accountid=439324)

You'll need to supply your accountid, which is the id of your network profile, not your per site userid.

```sql
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

create table #result (site sysname
                    , hostname sysname
                    , id integer
                    , postid integer
                    , score integer
                    , title nvarchar(200)
                    , text nvarchar(600))

select @sql = N'insert into #result' + STRING_AGG(concat(N'
select ''', name ,N''' as site
     , ''',hostname ,N'''
     , c.id
     , p.id
     , c.Score
     , q.title
     , Text
FROM ', convert(nvarchar(max),quotename(name)), N'.dbo.Comments c
inner join ', quotename(name), N'.dbo.posts p  on p.id = c.postid
inner join ', quotename(name), N'.dbo.posts q  on q.id = coalesce(p.parentid,p.id)
inner join ', quotename(name), N'.dbo.users u  on u.id = c.userid
where c.score > 0
and u.accountid = ##accountid##
'),N' 
union all')
from (select convert(nvarchar(max),name) name
    -- , convert(nvarchar(max),sitename)  sitename
    -- , meta
    -- , domain
     ,  concat( 
        -- based on an idea from Glorfindel 
        -- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321181
        (case sitename
        WHEN 'Audio' THEN 'video'
        WHEN 'Beer' THEN 'alcohol'
        WHEN 'CogSci' THEN 'psychology'
        WHEN 'Garage' THEN 'mechanics'
        WHEN 'Health' THEN 'medicalsciences'
        WHEN 'Moderators' THEN 'communitybuilding'
        WHEN 'Photography' THEN 'photo'
        WHEN 'Programmers' THEN 'softwareengineering'
        WHEN 'Vegetarian' THEN 'vegetarianism'
        WHEN 'Writers' THEN 'writing'
        WHEN 'Br' THEN 'pt'
        WHEN 'Mathoverflow' THEN concat((meta+'.'), sitename)
        ELSE case when sitename = domain then null else sitename end
        end +'.')
        , (case 
           when sitename <> 'mathoverflow' then (meta+'.') 
           else null 
           end) 
        , (case 
           when sitename <> 'mathoverflow' then concat((domain + '.'), 'com') 
           else 'net' 
           end)
        ) hostname
from (
select name
, case parsename(name,1) 
  when 'Meta' then parsename(name,2)
  else parsename(name,1) 
  end [sitename]
, case parsename(name,1) 
  when 'Meta' then 'meta'
  else null
  end [meta]
  , coalesce(parsename(name,3), parsename(name,2)) [domain]
from sys.databases
where database_id > 5
-- (name not like '%.Meta' or name = 'StackExchange.Meta')
) dbs
) dbsall

exec (@sql)



select site
     , concat('https://', hostname, '/posts/comments/', id, '|', text) [Link to Comment]
     , concat('https://', hostname, '/q/', postid, '|', title) [Link to Post]
     , score
from #result
order by score desc
```

When run today for your accountid (found on the url of your networkprofile) this will be your result:

[image]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the educational [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the awesome [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Comment: Wow! You are the ultimate of master of the stack exchange database. Thank you so much @rene. :)

Comment: Although this query would ignore comments that were later migrated to chat seeing as, for some reason unbeknownst to me, comments in chat lose upvotes.

Comment: Neat. My most upvoted comment has 555 votes. :D Thanks for the query!